# Error After Magento upgrade to 2.4.5-p1

Tags: error, magento2.4.5, abstract-class, php8

Im getting following error after upgrade to magento2.4.5-p1, while creating new customer account in frontend

```
    Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource in /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#1 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#2 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()
#3 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()
#4 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()
#5 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()
#6 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#7 /var/www/html/wff/generated/code/Magento/Newsletter/Model/SubscriberFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
#8 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Plugin/CustomerPlugin.php(328): Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory->create()
#9 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Plugin/CustomerPlugin.php(121): Magento\Newsletter\Model\Plugin\CustomerPlugin->getSubscriber()
#10 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Newsletter\Model\Plugin\CustomerPlugin->afterSave()
#11 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Plugin/CustomerRepository/TransactionWrapper.php(44): MDC\IntegrationsApi\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#12 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Customer\Model\Plugin\CustomerRepository\TransactionWrapper->aroundSave()
#13 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): MDC\IntegrationsApi\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#14 /var/www/html/wff/generated/code/MDC/IntegrationsApi/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository/Interceptor.php(32): MDC\IntegrationsApi\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#15 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php(949): MDC\IntegrationsApi\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor->save()
#16 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->createAccountWithPasswordHash()
#17 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->___callParent()
#18 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#19 /var/www/html/wff/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement/Interceptor.php(104): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#20 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php(896): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->createAccountWithPasswordHash()
#21 /var/www/html/wff/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Model/AccountManagement/Interceptor.php(95): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement->createAccount()
#22 /var/www/html/wff/app/code/MDC/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php(418): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->createAccount()
#23 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): MDC\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost->execute()
#24 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): MDC\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->___callParent()
#25 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Plugin/Account.php(64): MDC\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#26 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account->aroundExecute()
#27 /var/www/html/wff/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): MDC\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#28 /var/www/html/wff/generated/code/MDC/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost/Interceptor.php(41): MDC\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
```

I have override the default customer account create post controller and it is worked fine in magento 2.4.3 version

Here is my override controller

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface as CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Message\MessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Address;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Registration;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface as Encryptor;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry;
/**
 * Post create customer action
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CreatePost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost
{
    const DATA_UNDEFINED = 2;
    const DATA_CHANNEL = "web";
    
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
     * @param Address $addressHelper
     * @param UrlFactory $urlFactory
     * @param FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
     * @param RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory
     * @param AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory
     * @param CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory
     * @param CustomerUrl $customerUrl
     * @param Registration $registration
     * @param Escaper $escaper
     * @param CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor
     * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
     * @param CustomerRepository $customerRepository
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        Address $addressHelper,
        UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
        CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        Registration $registration,
        Escaper $escaper,
        CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
        CustomerRepository $customerRepository,
        \MDC\ConsentManagement\Model\ConsentAttributesFactory $concentAttr,
        \MDC\IntegrationsApi\Helper\Data $dynamicsHelper,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        Encryptor $encryptor,
        CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        Validator $formKeyValidator = null,
    ) {
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Validator::class);
        $this->consentAttributeModel = $concentAttr;
        $this->dynamicsHelper = $dynamicsHelper;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
        $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $customerSession,
            $scopeConfig,
            $storeManager,
            $accountManagement,
            $addressHelper,
            $urlFactory,
            $formFactory,
            $subscriberFactory,
            $regionDataFactory,
            $addressDataFactory,
            $customerDataFactory,
            $customerUrl,
            $registration,
            $escaper,
            $customerExtractor,
            $dataObjectHelper,
            $accountRedirect,
            $customerRepository
        );
    }
```

IntegrationApi Constructor code

```
class CustomerRepository extends \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository
{

    /**
     * @param CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     * @param CustomerSecureFactory $customerSecureFactory
     * @param CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry
     * @param AddressRepository $addressRepository
     * @param Customer $customerResourceModel
     * @param CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadata
     * @param CustomerSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResultsFactory
     * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter
     * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param ImageProcessorInterface $imageProcessor
     * @param JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor
     * @param CollectionProcessorInterface $collectionProcessor
     * @param NotificationStorage $notificationStorage
     * @param DelegatedStorage|null $delegatedStorage
     * @param GroupRepositoryInterface|null $groupRepository
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        CustomerSecureFactory $customerSecureFactory,
        CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        AddressRepository $addressRepository,
        Customer $customerResourceModel,
        CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadata,
        CustomerSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResultsFactory,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        ImageProcessorInterface $imageProcessor,
        JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor,
        CollectionProcessorInterface $collectionProcessor,
        NotificationStorage $notificationStorage,
        DelegatedStorage $delegatedStorage = null,
        ?GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository = null
    ) {
        $this->delegatedStorage = $delegatedStorage ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(DelegatedStorage::class);
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(GroupRepositoryInterface::class);
        parent::__construct(
            $customerFactory,
            $customerSecureFactory,
            $customerRegistry,
            $addressRepository,
            $customerResourceModel,
            $customerMetadata,
            $searchResultsFactory,
            $eventManager,
            $storeManager,
            $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
            $dataObjectHelper,
            $imageProcessor,
            $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor,
            $collectionProcessor,
            $notificationStorage,
            $delegatedStorage,
            $groupRepository
        );
    }
```

Can anyone help me to fix this error

Comment: Please, paste the constructor of this MDC/IntegrationsApi/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository

Comment: @RaulSanchez Question Updated with MDC/IntegrationsApi/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository constructor. Please check

Comment: Can't see it easily but there should be something wrong in that constructor. Maybe you can try moving that ObjectManager calls to separate methods

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @Black yes i have the issue is from other file, we have override a newsletter file and the parent constructor param are not passed properly that was the issue